Why it's till not bolded in my current file

The code I used in my current file is not work:
{\boldmath $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{r(t_0 +h) - r(t_0)}{h}$}

I use the same code in new file then it worked, but it's still not work in my current file. The same code in new file:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T5]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

{\boldmath $(x+y)(x-y)=x^{2}-y^{2}$ $\pi r^2$}
{\boldmath $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{r(t_0 +h) - r(t_0)}{h}$}

\end{document}


Please always include a small, but compilable test document in your questions. It should start with a class, the necessary packages and contain a document environment so people can simply copy&paste it to reproduce your problem.

If it works in a new file, that means something in your preamble may be the root cause. Have you used a different package? Try using \mathbf{} and see if that works in your original file? If you are unable to reproduce your own problem, it is certainly going to be more challenging for us to help.

I used \mathbf{} firstly but it didn't work. Then, I searched on google and saw a sample code used \boldmath{} but it didn't work too.

"didn't work" is not any information that allows people to help. LaTex will give a warning saying why bold is not available. (Many math fonts are not available in bold) but you have not provided a test document nor shown the warnings from the log.

it's impossible to debug an image but that \lim looks bold to me.

oh, I got it. Latex warning: Package mathptmx Warning: There are no bold math fonts on input line 172.

maybe i zoomed in pdf so it looked bold to you , but it's not bold as another text line

That is exactly why posting an image and no code is not a useful way to ask a question

If you want a Times-like font for your document, you need one that supports T5 for text and Times for math.
(Text from Wikipedia)
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% not really needed, avoids an annoying warning
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}

\usepackage{tgtermes,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

Việt Nam, quốc hiệu là Cộng hòa xã hội chủ nghĩa Việt Nam, là một 
quốc gia xã hội chủ nghĩa nằm ở cực Đông của bán đảo Đông Dương 
thuộc khu vực Đông Nam Á, giáp với Lào, Campuchia, Trung Quốc, 
biển Đông và vịnh Thái Lan.

$(x+y)(x-y)=x^{2}-y^{2}$\qquad $\pi r^2$

{\boldmath $(x+y)(x-y)=x^{2}-y^{2}$\qquad $\pi r^2$}

$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{r(t_0 +h) - r(t_0)}{h}$

{\boldmath $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{r(t_0 +h) - r(t_0)}{h}$}

\end{document}


